# How to initialize a POD struct while passing it as a variable?

Tags: c++

For instance i have a RECT and a some sub that has a RECT as a parameter

```
RECT wr = {0, 0, somevar1, somevar2};
someSub(wr);
```

Since i dont need the RECT anywhere else is there a way to initialize it as i send it to the sub? Something like

```
someSub(RECT {0, 0, somevar1, somevar2}); <- doesnt work :(
```

oh ya using vs2010 to compile

Comment: In a C++11-compliant compiler, you can do `someSub({0, 0, somevar1, somevar2});`.

Comment: This is in c++11 but according to a table I just checked that feature of c++11 isn't implemented by MSVC in that version.

Comment: In C99, `(RECT) {0, 0, somevar1, somevar2}` would be valid, and some compilers may also support this in C++ mode, but MSVC won't like that either.

Answer (score 1):

What I've did in the past is to create a substruct with a constructor:

```
struct Rect : RECT
{
    Rect(long l, long t, long r, long b)
    {
        left   = l;
        top    = t;
        right  = r;
        bottom = b;
    }
};

someSub(Rect(a, b, c, d));
```

The `Rect` itself is not a POD, because it has a constructor, but it will be *spliced* or downcasted into a `RECT` (or `RECT&`) on passing to the function.

Naturally, if you look at it, it is no different than creating a function:

```
RECT Rect(long l, long t, long r, long b)
{
    RECT r = {l, t, r, b};
    return r;
}
```

It even has the same syntax! But the constructor thing feels to me somewhat better.

Comment: Clever, but what advantage does this have over a simple `RECT Rect(long l, long t, long r, long b)` function?

Comment: @hvd: I was just adding that part. The advantage (if any) is that you can create many overloaded constructors and use it for both temporaries (as the OP requires) and for normal local variables. Yes, well, functions can also do this...

Comment: The constructor doesn't feel better to me, but that's okay. I was wondering whether there was any functional difference, such as any potential cases where function RVO cannot be applied but a constructor can construct the argument in-place.

Comment: @hvd- I think it's a matter of personal preference. Both syntaxes yield a identical r-value so both should be usable in exactly the same situations.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can inline the struct in the call:

```
func({0, 0, somevar1, somevar2});
```

In older versions of C/C++, you can create a helper function that initializes the structure and returns the result:

```
inline RECT new_RECT(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    RECT ret = {a, b, c, d};
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can call:

```
func(new_RECT(a, b, c, d));
```

and the struct creation should be inlined by the compiler.